# How to run forever async websocket client?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket

Im trying to use websocket for a client. The client send some start messages, after that, he can receive messages, whenever he sends something or not. The client is async, and I got some code from doc but I have no idea of what im doing with my life.

```
async def wsrun(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('hey')
        print(await websocket.recv()) # Starts receive things, not only once

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wsrun('wss://localhost:1515'))
```

The problem is, the websocket recv only shows the first thing that the server send :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I can't help you with your life, try this:

```
async def wsrun(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('hey')
        while True:
            print(await websocket.recv()) # Starts receive things, not only once

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wsrun('wss://localhost:1515'))
```

Comment: Thank you sir @drum. I think its working :v. But now I have a problem, I'm creating a discord bot, that integrates with my chat. Buuuuuuut. When I 'run' discord, the code hangs so the websocket doesnt initialize, and when I initialize my websocket, it hands and discord doesn't initialize. Running a async 'task' in another thread doesnt makes sense, do it?

Comment: Forget about it. I managed it to work. Also thank you again for the tip xD